# High Chart Issue on VS 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, highcharts

I have a serious Issue :(, I'm using High Charts controls on VS 2008 and everytime I made run to the web application I got that "Silly" RunTime Error :

> *missing compiler required member 'system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.ctor.*

I don't know the reason for that and I will appreciate any help !.

Comment: How your code looks like ?

Comment: The problem is not with the code at all.. it is about the DLL of HighCharts I think !! ... I can support you with the source code if u want

Comment: Is it DotNet.Highcharts? We used 2 different .NET wrappers for HighCharts but abandoned them as they were not updated to support the new properties/types in each successive highcharts release. It is much easier to do the charting (for us) in pure javascript where we build the JS code string in .NET using stringbuilder and script registration. Gets around a lot of the issues we were facing.

Comment: Can you provide me with a simple example of how to work with highCharts in .Net using JS Code ??

Comment: Here is a basic one in VB.net: http://dotnetfiddle.net/YxLiNL. You would need to build your seriesString and other items of course.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort but unfortunately I looked at your example you mentioned but it didn't work properly.however, I got the idea from what you mentioned ,but I tried many times and I didn't reach to any optimastic output :( !! Can you please give me mor help and update me with a C# Demo ??

Answer (score 0):

First of All I would like to thank everyone who commented on my stupid issue.Especially, wergeld (@wergeld),who gave me the first melody of the symphony:)...

My solution is a work around on that stupid compile error by writing the Javascript implementation of the chart using StringBuilder Class and this is the main idea of the work around.

lets stop chit chat :) and look at my humble work around:

First, I inserted all my Chart Implementation into a single class called "ChartImplementor.Cs" as following:

```
public enum ChartTypes
{
    pie,
    column,
    bar
}

public class ChartImplementor
{
    #region Member Variables
    string _title = String.Empty;
    string _subTitle = String.Empty;
    string _YTitle = string.Empty;
    string _XTitle = string.Empty;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string ChartTitle
    {
        set { _subTitle = value; }
        get { return _subTitle; }
    }

    public string ChartSubTitle
    {
        set { _title = value; }
        get { return _title; }
    }

    public string YTitle
    {
        set { _YTitle = value; }
        get { return _YTitle; }
    }

    public string XTitle
    {
        set { _XTitle = value; }
        get { return _XTitle; }
    }
    #endregion

   public string GenerateChartJS(ChartImplementor _chartObj,
        ChartTypes _chartType,
        Dictionary<object, object> _myXYDictionary, string _divID)
    {
        string newX_String = string.Empty;
        string newY_String = string.Empty;
        string ChartScript = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        if (_chartType == ChartTypes.column || _chartType == ChartTypes.bar)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> pair in _myXYDictionary)
            {
                string newXValue = String.Format("'{0}',", _myXYDictionary.Keys);
                newX_String += newXValue;
            }

            string XAxisData = string.Format("[{0}]", newX_String);

            builder.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");
            builder.Append("$(function () {");
            builder.Append("$('#" + _divID + "').highcharts({");
            builder.Append("chart: {type:'" + _chartType + "'},");
            builder.Append("title: {text:'" + _chartObj.ChartTitle + "'},");
            builder.Append("subtitle: {text:'" + _chartObj.ChartSubTitle + "'},");
            builder.Append("xAxis: {title: { text:'" + _chartObj.XTitle + "'},categories:" + XAxisData + ",labels:{enabled:false}},");
            builder.Append("yAxis: { min: 0, title: { text:'" + _chartObj.YTitle + "'}},");
            builder.Append("tooltip: {headerFormat: '<span style=font-size:10px></span>");
            builder.Append("<table style=direction: rtl>',");
            builder.Append("pointFormat: '<tr><td style=color:{series.color};padding:0>{series.name}: </td><td style=padding:0><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',");
            builder.Append("footerFormat: '</table>',");
            //builder.Append("shared: true,");
            builder.Append("useHTML: true},");
            builder.Append("plotOptions: { column: { pointPadding: 0.2, borderWidth: 0}},");
            builder.Append("series:[");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> pair in _myXYDictionary)
            {
                string newXValue = String.Format("'{0}'", pair.Key);
                builder.Append("{ name:");
                builder.Append("" + newXValue + "");
                builder.Append(",data: ");
                builder.Append("[" + pair.Value + "]},");
            }
            builder.Append("]});");
            builder.Append("});");
            builder.Append("</script>");
            ChartScript = builder.ToString();

        }
        else if (_chartType == ChartTypes.pie)
        {
            builder.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>");
            builder.Append("$(function () {");
            builder.Append("$('#" + _divID + "').highcharts({");
            builder.Append("chart: {plotBackgroundColor: null,plotBorderWidth: null,plotShadow: false},");
            builder.Append("title: {text:'" + _chartObj.ChartTitle + "'},");
            //{series.name}: 
            builder.Append("tooltip: { pointFormat: '<b{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'},");
            builder.Append("plotOptions: { pie: {allowPointSelect: true,cursor: 'pointer',dataLabels: { enabled: true, color: '#000000',connectorColor: '#000000',    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'}}},");
            builder.Append("series:[{type: 'pie',data:[");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> pair in _myXYDictionary)
            {
                string newXValue = String.Format("['{0}',{1}],", pair.Key, pair.Value);
                builder.Append(newXValue);
            }
            builder.Append("]}] });");
            builder.Append("});");
            builder.Append("</script>");
            ChartScript = builder.ToString();
        }
        return ChartScript;

    }

}
```

As it can be seen from the class that the target method contains 4 parameters:
  1.An instance of the ChartImplementer Class.
  2.An Object from ChartTypes Enumeration.
  3.An Object od a dictionary that its key and value are from an Object DataTypes(This             Dictionary will take the X/Y Cordinates of the chart for Binding it).
  4.The ID of the Control which will populate the Chart staff.

I have implemented the Datasource of the chart in a Dictionary Control and I passed it as a parameter in the Target Page As Following:

```
    protected void ImageButtonPopulateChart_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int? genderID = null;
        Dictionary<object, object> myXyDataObjects = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        ChartImplementor charting = new ChartImplementor()
        {
            ChartTitle = "A digram illustrates Employees ",
            ChartSubTitle = "HSBC Bank.",
            XTitle = "Employees",
            YTitle = "Salaries"

        };


        var chartQuery = SchoolDC.usp_Chart_Report(SchoolID, genderID, statusID).ToList();
        foreach (var item in chartQuery)
        {
            myXyDataObjects.Add(item.LevelName, item.stCount);
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1,
UpdatePanel1.GetType(),
"script",charting.GenerateChartJS(charting, ChartTypes.column, myXyDataObjects, "container"), // container is the ID of the Div Control which will populate the Chart.
false);
}
```

This is the .aspx page :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    </div>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonPopulateChart" runat="server" onclick="ImageButtonPopulateChart_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

N.B: To be able to populate the Chart you need to invoke Highcharts.Js Script, and Exporting.Js Script which it is responsible for exporting the Chart in many different Formats(I like that feature:) ).

**RIP Steve Jobs said,We're just enthusiastic about what we do.I'm very enthusiastic about sharing my solution to you here, so please if you revise my code and find something that can make the code looks more better or even any other crazy idea don't hesitate to advice me :).**

**I wish a happy day for everyone.**